# Show hidden web table

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to scrape a table but can't seem to make it visible.

The table is on this [page](https://www.findacode.com/code.php?set=CPT&c=0001U) after you expand the 'Code History' section in light purple. Login credentials are below but also easy to get from a trial account:

- username = jd@mailinator.com
- password = m%$)-Y95*^.1Gin+

Below's a graphic illustrating the data I'm trying to get to. I'm interested in the bottom row:

[image]

Here's the code I'm using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver_path = "path to chromedriver.exe"
url_login = "https://www.findacode.com/signin.html"
url_code = "https://www.findacode.com/code.php?set=CPT&c="
username = 'jd@mailinator.com'
password = 'm%$)-Y95*^.1Gin+'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, chrome_options=options)

driver.get(url_login)
form = driver.find_element_by_name('login')
form.find_element_by_name('id').send_keys(username)
form.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)
form.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Sign In']").submit()

driver.get(url_code+'0001U')
driver.find_element_by_id('history').click()
```

At this point, when I look in `driver.page_source`, I was expecting elements of the table to be visible but that's not the case. Where's the flaw in my thinking?

Comment: Thanks to users who tried to mask the password but I intended to share the password as that account was created for testing and login credentials are necessary to see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This site loads fragments of the page when it's needed (aka lazy loading). Therefore, the actual contents will be loaded when that portion of the page is expanded. This helps when your "trial" expires, the server can return generic content back to prevent unauthorized access.

I can see 3 ways to remedy this:

1. Wait for the data to be available after `#history.click()` and the content divs are loaded (following `.sectionbody` div is not empty).
2. Get the data from the fragment by directly calling the same URL after logging in. i.e. `.get("https://www.findacode.com/logs/codepage_stats.php?section=sh_history_div&set=CPT&c=0001U")`
3. Utilize their built-in auto-open feature my checking the appropriate checkbox once, then load all the data you expect normally in future requests.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try these beginning with option 3 and see how it goes.